# Scatter plot with a circle in it

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, linegraph

I was planning to do a scatter plot with 5000 data points with a line of unit circle in the same plot, but the code I have right now show a pretty small plot with huge dots in it. I tried to make this plot size larger but `plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))` doesn't work....wonder what did I do wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x=scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=5000)
y=scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=5000)
a=np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200))
b=np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200))


plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(a,b, color="red")
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`plt.figure()` creates a new empty plot.  You should call it before the other plotting functions

You can set a smaller dotsize, e.g `plt.scatter(x, y, s=1)`. To force that the circle is shown as a circle, set an equal aspect ratio (`set_aspect('equal')`).

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=5000)
y = scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=5000)
a = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200))
b = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200))

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1)
plt.plot(a, b, color="red")
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

To change the `figsize` after the plot has been created, you can use:

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 15)
```

Matplotlib also provides a function to create a circle. Here is an example setting a semi-transparent `facecolor`:

```
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=5000)
y = scipy.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2, size=5000)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, facecolor='#FF000011', edgecolor='red'))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: using plt.Circle]

Comment: it works, thanks! but what if we want to enlarge the plot size?

Comment: You change the figsize in the call to `plt.figure(figsize=...)`?